# Tiny mce height different in different browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tinymce

I have this code in my JS:

```
tinyMCE.init({
        width: "100%",
        height: "550",
});
```

yet the height on the tinymce is seen differently in different browser. Any idea how can we solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how big the differences are. 
But probably it is because each browser has differences in rendering textarea's, buttons etc.

Comment: The difference is too big atleast 50-80 pixels.

Comment: That is kind of weird. You sure that it is not some custom CSS or inline breaks/newlines that are causing this?

Comment: Thing also happening when you use TinyMCE in a plain (newly created) html page with no extra css etc.?